# How to get jquery nested accordion working?

Tags: php, jquery, accordion

I am trying to create a UI comprising of jquery accordion in which the years will be listed and when someone clicks on a year it should expand and inside there should be another similar accordion which will have all the invoice numbers for that particular year. I tried printing values with php and valus are printing correctly.

php code is

```
<?php   
    include('validateuser.php');
    if(isset($_GET['customername']))
    {       
        $flag=validate($_GET['customername'],$z);   
        if($flag==1) 
        {
            $ccodeforquery=$_GET['customername'];
            $cnamesql=mysql_query("select * from custcode where Cust_code='$ccodeforquery'");
            if($cnamesql==FALSE)
                die(mysql_error());
            while($rowforcname=mysql_fetch_array($cnamesql)) { 
            ?>          
                <?php echo "Purchase History of ".$rowforcname['Cust_Name']; } ?>
                <?php if($count2<>0) { ?>
                <a href="#pop4" class="classname">Add</a><?php } ?>                     
            <div id="accordion">
            <?php               
                $j=$_GET["customername"];
                $_SESSION['cn']=$j;     
                //echo $j;
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchase_history where Cust_code='$j' group by year(date) desc");
                if($result==FALSE)
                    die(mysql_error());
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                $dateArray = explode('-', $row['date']);
                $year = current($dateArray);                
                //$theData[$year][] = $row;
                ?>

                  <h3><?php echo $year; ?></h3>
                  <div>
                    <p>                     
                        <?php $resultyear=mysql_query("select * from purchase_history where Cust_code='$j' and year(date)= '$year'");
                                if($resultyear==FALSE)
                                    die(mysql_error());
                                while($rowyear=mysql_fetch_array($resultyear)) {                                
                        ?>                                                                          
                    </p>                        
                        <div class="accordian2">
                        <h3><a href="#"><?php echo $rowyear['invoice_no']; } ?></a></h3>
                        <div>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>                          
                <?php }  ?>
            </div>
        <center><?php } else { ?>
            <img src="/images/Access-Denied.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
        <?php } } ?></center>
```

I have attached a screen shot of the output.
Without using a nested accordion the output is coming like
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7fhcd4s127sl1r/capture1.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r29j9df9riiwwsn/capture2.png

After adding inside accordion the output is like 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdtnlznq44sqcag/capture3.png

I have created a fiddle. Link is http://jsfiddle.net/p3Dnp/
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you share the generated html and the script you tried? create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if possible

Comment: I have attached the output html. You can get an idea what the problem is. If I create a fiddle I guess it will work fine if static. Problem is arising with dynamically generated data

Comment: you won't know whether fiddle will work or not until you try it...

Comment: @ArunPJohny I created the fiddle. The link is http://jsfiddle.net/p3Dnp/